# How to make upper category on the left side in JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, data-visualization

I really want to make a upper category of in JSON data structure.
But I can't find any way to do that.

Below is my code.

```
    [
  {
    "name": "john",
    "age": 30,
    "hometown": "seoul"
  },
  {
    "name": "mike",
    "age": 30,
    "hometown": "LA"
  },
  {
    "name": "xin",
    "age": 30,
    "hometown": "chengdu"
  }
]
```

The above JSON Format creates the data structure as below.

[image: Table Generated by JSON]

The data structure I want to achieve is something like below.
[image]

To do this, I need to set an upper category value like colleague/ friends on the left hand side.
I tried for a few hours, but still couldn't figure out the way to add the upper category on the left hand side.

Is it impossible in JSON? or Does anyone know how to do that?
Please help me...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please mark correct answer if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this could help, you'd need to add they required "key" to your JSON Object array, in this case - `friends` and `colleagues` :

```
{
  "friends": [
    {
      "name": "john",
      "age": 30,
      "hometown": "seoul"
    },
    {
      "name": "mike",
      "age": 30,
      "hometown": "LA"
    },
    {
      "name": "xin",
      "age": 30,
      "hometown": "chengdu"
    }
  ],
  "colleagues": [
    {
      "name": "tim",
      "age": 30,
      "hometown": "chicago"
    },
    {
      "name": "kim",
      "age": 30,
      "hometown": "Newjersey"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
{
   "groups":[
      "name",
      "age",
      "hometown"
   ],
   "friends":[
      {
         "name":"john",
         "age":30,
         "hometown":"seoul"
      },
      {
         "name":"mike",
         "age":30,
         "hometown":"LA"
      },
      {
         "name":"xin",
         "age":30,
         "hometown":"chengdu"
      }
   ],
   "colleagues":[
      {
         "name":"tim",
         "age":30,
         "hometown":"chicago"
      },
   ]
}
```